# Edit spring boot app configuration environment variables in Visual Code launch file

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

Can one edit the spring boot app configuration environment variables in Visual Code?
In eclipse (STS) one can do that by going to Debug Configuration >> Spring boot app >> Configuration >> Environment Variables.

is there any way to do it in Visual Code by editing some launch file?

if it's not done an error will come every time i run it:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userInfo in blabla2 required a bean of type 'com.blabla3.UserInfo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=Pro)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.blabla3.UserInfo' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can edit the launch file using `Run > Open Configurations`.
Then, add the following lines:

```
    "env": {
        "MY_ENV_VARIABLE": "value1",
        "SECOND_ENV_VARIABLE":"value2"
    },
```

Comment: To make things clearer, here is a full example file:
```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "ApiApplication",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "io.sample.api.ApiApplication",
      "projectName": "api",
      "env": {
        "MONGO_HOST": "localhost",
        "MONGO_PORT": "27020",
      }
    }
  ]
}

```